# How do I return a char from a char pointer function in C?

Tags: c, return-value, c-strings, return-type, function-definition

i recently made a function that finds the smallest character in a string. I am not sure how to return the smallest character in a char pointer function.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char * smallest(char s[]) 
{
    char  small = 'z';

    int i = 0;

    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[i] < small)
        {
            small = s[i];
        }

        i++;
    }

    return small;
}


int main(void)
{
    char s[4] = "dog"; 
    printf("%c",smallest(s));
}
```

Comment: A few errors:
```smallest()``` has return type ```char*``` but you try to return a ```char```.
Also ```smallest(s[4] == 'd')``` is both a typo and wrong altogether, you're looking for ```smallest(s) == 'd'```
I have no idea what you're using assert for here instead of an if statement but it works.

Comment: It's good practice to have function names with a verb and in a form that explain what it does.  For example `findSmallestChar()`.

Comment: Did you want to return a pointer to the smallest char, or the char itself?  Either is possible.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `small` has the type `char` according to its declaration

```
char small = 'z';

//...

return small;
```

and this variable is returned from the function while the function return type is the pointer type `char *`.

```
char * smallest(char s[])
```

Also if the user will pass an empty string to the function then you will try to return the character `'z'` as a smallest character though this character is absent in the empty string.

I think in this case you should return a pointer to the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
char * smallest( char s[] ) 
{
    char *small = s;

    if ( *s )
    {
        while ( *++s )
        {
           if ( *s < *small ) small = s;
        }
    }

    return small;
}
```

Or as in C there is no function overloading then the function should be declared and defined like

```
char * smallest( const char s[] ) 
{
    const char *small = s;

    if ( *s )
    {
        while ( *++s )
        {
           if ( *s < *small ) small = s;
        }
    }

    return ( char * )small;
}
```

Pay attention to that this `assert`

```
assert(smallest(s[4] == 'd'));
```

is incorrect, It seems you mean

```
assert( *smallest( s ) == 'd');
```

Or after you updated your program you need to write

```
printf("%c\n",*smallest(s));
```

instead of

```
printf("%c",smallest(s));
```

Using this function you can not only to find the smallest character but also to determine its position in the source string.

For example

```
char *small = smallest( s );

printf( "The smallest character is '%c' at the position %tu\n", 
        *small, small - s );
```

or

```
char *small = smallest( s );

if ( *small == '\0' )
{
    puts( "The source string is empty" );
}
else
{
    printf( "The smallest character is '%c' at the position %tu\n", 
            *small, small - s ); 
}
```

Comment: Man, you have been working hard lately! I'll have to up my game...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am glad to see you.:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your program.

### 1. Wrong parameters

The function `smallest(char[] s)`expects to be given an character array but what you are passing in as an argument is `s[4] == 'd'` which is not a character array.
This has nothing to do with the `assert()` itself.

What you want to do is `assert(smallest(s) == 'd')`.

### 2. Wrong return type

Your function is declares that it would return `*char` (= a pointer to a char) but you are trying to return a `char`. So you should adjust the return type of your function to be `char`.

The correct program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

char smallest(char s[]) {
    char small = 'z';

    int i = 0;

    while(s[i] != '\0') {
    
        if (s[i] < small) {
            small = s[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return small;
}

int main(void) {

    char s[4] = "dog"; 

    assert(smallest(s) == 'd');
    printf("Passed\n");
}
```